# Help with wifi hotspots please!

Tags: wireless

I know I can make wifi hotspots on Ubuntu 14.04 wired -> wifi. BUT. Can I make a hotspot wifi -> wifi? If so, how?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/498257/edit) your question and make it clearer - what you want to do, what you have tried, etc.

Answer (score -1):

No You Cannot, This sort of negates the purpose of the hotspot function. If you have a wifi connection on your PC, then that same wifi connection is available to other devices. If this is the case, why do you need ANOTHER hotspot? Besides, I think the hotspot needs the wifi radio to serve up the hotspot. I'm not sure, but I don't think it can do that and connect to another wifi connection at the same time.